# Mysql query for price comparison

Tags: mysql, comparison

I am working on a price comparison program. I have three websites. In my database I have three tables for the webshops. Each tables has a price and a product_id column. I want to list all the product_id-s and see the prices in every webshop. The product id is unique, but not the same in all of the tables, as not all webshop has the same products. I am working with mysql, but I'm very new to databases. What query should I try?

Comment: is there anything other in the tables the same in all tables (for comparision)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you have a "master" product table, that lists all products, regardless of whether they are sold on *all* sites, or just one. Then join from that to each of the website pricing tables.  Try matching on product name. In its simplest form, the query wold look like:

```
select
  p.*,
  t1.price as site1_price,
  t2.price as site2_price,
  t3.price as site3_price
from product p
left join website1 t1 on t1.name = p.name
left join website2 t2 on t2.name = p.name
left join website2 t3 on t3.name = p.name;
```

You might have to try joining on brand and model, ie `on t1.brand = p.brand and t1.model = p.model`, or some other criteria if name is not unique.

site prices will be null if they don't sell a product.

To quickly populate product, you could run this:

```
insert into product (name, brand, model, ...)
select name, brand, model, ... from website1
union 
select name, brand, model, ... from website2
union 
select name, brand, model, ... from website3;
```

FYI, the use of `UNION` (rather than `UNION ALL`) makes the output of the union produce only unique rows