# Price Comparison engine issues in fetching same product with different name conventions

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a price comparison website and have two table from two different sites for eg. one from snapdeal and one from infibeam.

The table structure is as below and is same for both the sites.

productname
productprice

I am using like query for searching a product.

The problem for eg. when I search for "iphone 6s 16gb space gray" which is a product name in snapdeal while the same product is named as "apple iphone 6s (16gb) space gray".

How do I perform a price comparison operation for the same product from two different tables in php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql query for price comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820594/mysql-query-for-price-comparison)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use something like [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) from MySQL for searching for similar products.

So you would do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `productname` LIKE '%search_query%';
```

But honestly, there is a better way to approach this problem.

You should have a table structured like along with an example of values:

```
productname   | productprice | productsearch
------------------------------------------
iphone 16gb   |          500 | iphone 16gb
iphone (16gb) |          450 | iphone 16gb
```

So what the purpose of the `productsearch` field is to hold the value of `productname` stripped of all special characters (like the brackets).

Now when you feed the search query, assuming you are using PHP:

```
$search_query = str_replace(' ', '-', $search_query);
$search_query = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $search_query);
$search_query = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $search_query);
```

Now the `$search_query` will contains a cleaned string of all special characters and so now `apple iphone 6s (16gb) space gray` -> `apple iphone 6s 16gb space gray`